# Linq test for null or empty fields

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-entities

This is what I have tried

```
Dim B = (From r In _db.Personnel _
         Where !(r.BldgDist.Trim() = String.Empty) _
         Order By r.BldgDist _
         Select r.BldgDist).ToList().Distinct()
For Each ab In B
    list.Add(New ListItem(ab.BldgDist, ab.BldgDist))
Next
```

But at the bang it tells me that an identifier is expected. Not sure I understand what is missing. I am just trying to eliminate the null values and empty string values, before I load into a list.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: but when I do that, I get an intellisence that tells me that ab.BldgDist is not a member of 'String', when the property is declared a string

Answer (score 3):

VB.Net doesn't recognize `!` but you can use the `<>` or `Not` operator instead.

```
Dim B = (From r In _db.Personnel _
     Where (r.BldgDist.Trim() <> String.Empty) _
     ...
```

Comment: when I change it to Not, I get an intellisense that the ab.BldgDist is not a member of 'String' even though the property is declared as a string.

Comment: I can't tell why that happens from the excerpt you posted. What happens if you use `<>` or `String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.BldgDist.Trim())`?

Comment: @TomS The second error is due to the fact that the first query returns a List<String>, and assigns it to B. When you then are foreach'ing over B, variable "ab" will be a string. You can't then do "ab.BldgDist" inside the loop. You should replace the body with "list.Add(New ListItem(ab,ab))" (after already doing the change proposed by Dennis

Comment: I changed the query to be <> as indicated above and then in the for each loop did the list.Add(New ListItem(ab,ab)) and that worked. I guess my question is... Does the (ab,ab) work because I only have a single value for both the display and value? I have other lists where I have been able to identify the specific fields from my list to use as the display and value fields. Thanks again.

Comment: This depends on the actual implementation. Please accept the answer, if it was a helpful solution to your original question.

Answer (score 1):

[`!`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2kd6eb2) is a C# operator, not VB.  Use [`Not`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cwcswt4.aspx) instead (or [`<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cey92b0t)).  For example:

```
Where Not (r.BldgDist.Trim() = String.Empty)
```

Or

```
Where r.BldgDist.Trim() <> String.Empty
```